# Publishing and choosing app version (alpha/beta/prod) in google play store (android)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

to be short - we have an application, that connects to different environments on different versions (alpha - test server, prod - prod server). My problem is that the client is signed to alpha test and wants to easily change environment (test/prod). As far as I know, this could be done only by downloading different version of app, but they can download only the newest available (max(alpha, prod, beta)) and cannot choose version manually.
Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: How do you manage your versions? One approach could be to provide an option in your app settings to choose the targeted server when the app is not in release (prod) version.

Comment: At the moment we're managing versions manually - when releasing to prod we're changing config and rebuilding apk. But that is not the issue - we want to give the user the ability to change environment without implementing gui in application.

Comment: So if you don't want to implement gui, you'll have to provide your client different versions of your app if you want him to test on different servers.

Comment: Yes, I want to give client two versions, but I don't see any way to achieve this besides of creating completely new app in play store.

Comment: But I don't see why you want your client to change the server version of the app. Prod, Beta and Alpha are supposed to be 3 different versions of the app, and the difference should not be only the server's endpoint. 
But your client can have 3 different Google accounts, each one linked to a different version of the app, and the only thing he would have to do is to log with the appropriate one on his device and reinstall the app. It will automatically download the correct version.

Comment: Because production version has sensitive data connected to many 3rd party systems. Testing it would for example cause real debt collection, generate a payment or damage claim on the client. Using 3 accounts is a weak solution :/

Comment: You can't do what you want to do. You'll have to either have a different Google account for each app version (one links to prod, one links to beta and one links to alpha), or published 3 apps on the Play Store (!), or add a gui for the user to manually switched (must be deactivated in the release). But I still don't understand why you want your user to switch server.